# Reference a cell on a newly created worksheet with user created name

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to this so apologies if its something simple but hopefully someone can help.
I have an input box to add a new person to a table. This then copies a template and is renamed to the persons name. I need reference cell I3 and others on the new sheet that has been created to be entered into the table next to their name. Below is the code i have got so far

```
'input box to get new user name and check if valid and create new sheet
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Player Template")
    Dim newws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, newname
    Dim query As Long, xst As Boolean, info As String

retry:
xst = False
newname = Application.InputBox("Please Enter New players Name.", info, , , , , , 2)
If newname = "False" Then Exit Sub
For Each sh In wb.Sheets
    If sh.Name = newname Then
        xst = True: Exit For
        End If
Next
If Len(newname) = 0 Or xst = True Then
    info = "Name is invalid. Please Retry."
    GoTo retry
End If
ws.Copy after:=ws: Set newws = ActiveSheet: newws.Name = newname


Sheets("Table").Select
Range("C6").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = newname
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value =
```

I don't know what code to add to the end to reference the cells i need in the table other than do it manually after the person has been added. I have looked for answers but found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code copies a sheet called "player template" and creates it under the name from inputbox. References from range I3:M3 are copied to next free row in sheet "table" column "C". C & lastrow get's player's sheet name and columns to the right of the name are filled with the references to that sheet

```
Option Explicit

Sub paste_to_table()

Dim last_tblrow As Double
Dim tblwks As Worksheet, newwks As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
Dim targetrng As Range
Dim newname As String
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Player Template")
Set tblwks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Table")
Dim query As Long, xst As Boolean, info As String

retry:
xst = False
newname = Application.InputBox("Please Enter New players Name.", info, , , , , , 2)
If newname = "False" Then Exit Sub
For Each sh In wb.Sheets
    If sh.Name = newname Then
        xst = True: Exit For
        End If
Next
If Len(newname) = 0 Or xst = True Then
    info = "Name is invalid. Please Retry."
    GoTo retry
End If
ws.Copy After:=ws: Set newwks = ActiveSheet: newwks.Name = newname

'get last row of "table" column "C"
last_tblrow = tblwks.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

'set targetrng range variable to next empty cell of column C
Set targetrng = tblwks.Range("C" & last_tblrow + 1)
'newname value into next empty row of column C
targetrng.Value = newname
'next value into "D7" to of "table" wks from cell "I3","I4","I5".....

targetrng.Offset(0, 1).Value = "=" & newwks.Name & "!" & newwks.Cells(3, 9).Address
targetrng.Offset(0, 2).Value = "=" & newwks.Name & "!" & newwks.Cells(3, 10).Address
targetrng.Offset(0, 3).Value = "=" & newwks.Name & "!" & newwks.Cells(3, 11).Address
targetrng.Offset(0, 4).Value = "=" & newwks.Name & "!" & newwks.Cells(3, 12).Address
targetrng.Offset(0, 5).Value = "=" & newwks.Name & "!" & newwks.Cells(3, 13).Address

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried the code and it seems to work ok for the one cell i tried but it brings back a value of zero. I think this is my fault as i did not mention in the original question that the new sheet that gets created is populated weekly so i need it to actually reference the cell not just get the value. New names could be added each week. I have the names going down column C and then results going across for 10 weeks. As an example from the test i just ran i need the cell in D to show ='chris test1'!I3 and not the value of 0 as it has not data yet?

Comment: Run_time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error

I have tried amending the code to the following
        targetrng.Offset(0, 1).Formula2R1C1 = newwks.Cells(3, 9)
but then i get 
Run_time error '1004':

Application-defined or object-defined error

it does work using the below code but references the wrong cell no matter if i amend the row to
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='" & newname & "'!R[-78]C[5]"

Comment: Dear Chris unfortunately I don't understand your question anymore.  You have a workbook which has a sheet called "Player Template". and maybe several sheets with the names entered from last run. Now an inputbox where a player name is entered and this name has to be the name of a new created sheet which is actually a copy of the template sheet "Player Template". There is another sheet called "Table" which has information in it  which needs to be filled in the player's sheet but with code or formulas referencing to cells within this "Table" sheet?

Comment: Player sheets have data you want summarized in "Table" sheet? Will the Player data change and therefore be updated on "Table" sheet by formula ref?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Each person has a player sheet created, the main table has the players listed. Players data is entered weekly into their own sheet. I need the table sheet to pick up the data that has been totalled. Each week has a different location for the total on the player sheet and it runs over 10 weeks.

Comment: Have you tested the current code? It should do what you need

Comment: The code I tried gave the value which was 0 as no data had been entered when the sheet is created so when I entered data in the player sheet it didn’t update the player table. I am at work at the moment but if you have any more code for me to try I will give it a go after 10pm (GMT).

Comment: For me "table" sheet is updating when I enter data in the newly created player sheet (remember atm cells I3-M3). The 0 entries only happen when I set the calculation mode to "xlCalculationManual". Therefore check bottom-left if there is written "calculate". In my XL version saving the file performs calculation, but only once. Next changes are not updating calculations. Also remember that calculation mode persist after reopen. Therefore make sure to add at the end: application.calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Comment: Tried again when i got back last night and copied and amended one bit as kept going to open something. 
It now looks like 
targetrng.Offset(0, 0).Value = "=" & "'" & newwks.Name & "'!" & newwks.Cells(3, 9).Address
I have added the lines to get rest of the cells i need and it works great. 
Thank you for all your help

Comment: that's good that it works now. You can mark it then as completed.